# Too small to represent and Chop in inaccessible algorithm

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions, machine-precision

### Overview

I want to apply a specified `Chop` function to every step in an function call in Mathematica (in my case `LegendreP`), especially when encountering a machine underflow error. The resulting function should be applicable to a dataframe.

### The Setup

I am trying to calculate a function including an associated Legendre function with complex indices

`function[t_] = 1/Sin[t] * LegendreP[-1/2 + V * I, l+1, Cos[t]]`

where t is between `0` and `Pi`, `V` is of order of magnitude `10` and `l` is between `10` and `100`. Beside the function I need its logarithmic derivative `function'/function`.

Ideally I want to do this by applying the function to a dataframe and appending the result in a separate column.

`Append[#, "function" -> function[#timeframe]]`

where timeframe is a column with all the t values.

### The Problem

When I run this code for any `l` bigger than 12 and very small `t~1e-5` values, the LegendreP Algorithm throws a machine underflow error `General::munfl` because it cannot execute a multiplication of extremly small complex numbers.

While for a single call or a plot, it seems to do some chopping or return `Indeterminate`, when I write it to a dataframe with

`Append[#, "function" -> function[#timeframe]]`

it just returns Failure and does not write anything to the dataframe.

### What I have tried so far

I have tried to use `Chop` and `Threshold`, but this does not seem to apply to the single steps of the algorithm but only the final result.

The way I "solve" the problem at the moment is to catch the error and return `0` instead of my function. This is not ideal since the real or imaginary part of the step in question and the result might not be negligible while the other one is, or it might diverge instead of converge to `0`.

Since the multiplication that raises the error lists numbers ~1e-300 or so, I doubt that the problem is solvable by increasing the precision.

### My Goal

Ideally I'd like to call Chop, whenever Mathematica encounters a machine underflow. The behavior of Chop on complex numbers is exactly what I need. This way I should be able to preserve the real or imaginary part that does not vanish.

Is the error handling different, when applied to a dataframe as it relates to this question (for plots or even single evaluation points I don't have the same issue) or can an indeterminate/NaN be written to a dataframe?

Is there a way to set a "global chop rule"?

Grateful for any hint :D

### Edit 1:

"Minimal" Example:

````
potentialValue = 77.5;
l = 25;

data = Dataset[{
   <|"timeframe" -> 0.000001|>,
   <|"timeframe" -> 0.000002|>,
   <|"timeframe" -> 0.000003|>
   }]


vacuumFluctuation[t_] = 
  1/Sin[t] LegendreP[-(1/2) + I Sqrt[potentialValue], l + 1, Cos[t]];

firstDerivative[t_] = D[vacuumFluctuation[x], x] /. x -> t;

logarithmicDerivative[t_] = firstDerivative[t]/vacuumFluctuation[t];

data = data[All, 
   Append[#, 
     "vacuum_fluctuation_logarithmic_derivative_mathematica" -> 
      logarithmicDerivative[#timeframe]] &];

data
```
````

Comment: What’s a dataframe? Can you add the complete executable code for your operation, perhaps on a small toy example that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: `munfl` means the number was replaced by zero, so neither `Threshold` nor `Chop` should be of any use internally at such steps.

Comment: @MarcoB  Sorry, in Mathematica it's called a Dataset. See Edit. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @MichaelE2 How can it still crash with "too small to represent" instead of producing 0, then?

Comment: I interpreted “chopping or return `Indeterminate`” as doing something like `10.^-310` or `10.^-310/10.^-310`.  I don’t see how to use `Threshold` to prevent getting `0.` or `Indeterminate` in these two cases.  (You will get the `munfl` message, but that’s just a warning that it’s chopping the result to zero. I wouldn’t call is a “crash.”)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right. Upon further investigation, my code crashed at a later point and when displaying the dataset, wrote the munfl WARNING into the dataset, even though it had very little to do with the actual error. Sorry for the confusion, I am still struggling a bit with the Mathematica stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `General::munfl` only occurs for machine numbers. So, you can fix the issue by using arbitrary precision numbers internally, and then converting to a machine number:

```
function[t_, V_, l_] := N @ ReleaseHold[
    SetPrecision[Hold[1/Sin[t]*LegendreP[-1/2+V*I,l+1,Cos[t]]], 30]
]
```

Then:

```
function[.00001, 10, 50]
```

> 1.34228*10^-189 + 0. I

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind explaining what the logic is behind the function/ decorator sequence?